# Is there a name for a section and a retraction together?

Tags: category-theory

I call $(s, r)$ such that $r\circ s =\operatorname{id}$ a **split morphism**. (Other names are “section-retraction pair”, “split pair.”) Notice that this is not a section, because any section is **one** morphism. I want to make sure that no official name exists thus I can invent it myself. Do you know the name?

The same question about isomorphisms. “Isomorphism pair”, “isomorphic pair”?

The distinction may be quite apparent. Every split morphism is a categorical diagram whereas a section is not.

Comment: There is a notion of a split epi/monomorphism, but it isn't defined as a pair of morphisms. This seems more useful in a algebraic or constructive setting...

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Split monomorphism is just a synonym for section. I read Wikipedia before. :)

Comment: Have you settled on any terminology? I want to use it. For the second concept, I think "isomorphism pair" is a good name.

Comment: @user18921: No. I leave it to you.

Answer (score 3):

*Very late answer...*

According to Borceux-Bourn [*] this is a "point" (if you assume categories are named after their objects in some sense).

The points in a category $\mathcal A$ together with pairs of morphisms making the obvious diagrams commute form a category $\mathsf{Pt}(\mathcal A)$, the *category of points of $\mathcal A$*. Assuming $\mathcal A$ has pullbacks along split epis, the "codomain functor" $\mathsf{Pt}(\mathcal A)\to \mathcal A$ is called the *fibration of points* (it is a fibration in this case). The fibration of points is useful to classify various notions between (let's say) $\mathcal A$ being *Mal'cev* and $\mathcal A$ being *essentially affine* (Abelian minus [pointed & has cokernels]).

I suppose the name "point" comes from the fact that the fiber $\mathsf{Pt}_A$ of the codomain functor over $A$ is (essentially) the *category of pointed objects* of the slice category $\mathcal A \downarrow A$. The category of pointed objects of a category $\mathcal B$ with a terminal object $\mathbf{1}$ is the coslice category $\mathsf{1} \downarrow \mathcal B$, which is, you guessed it, pointed.

[*] F. Borceux, D. Bourn - "Mal’cev, protomodular, homological and semi-abelian categories"

Comment: This isn’t a bad answer, but it’s certainly not the case that anyone would understand you if you just threw out this use of the word “point”.

Comment: @KevinCarlson True. Certainly I would expect anyone using this term to define it beforehand.